# Add every five lines in the column then divide by ten?

Tags: r, excel, csv

I have three columns in R file, Looks like this;

```
X61253 X61613 X66198
279    140    140
279    139    139
278    139    139
279    140    140
279    139    139
278    139    139
3624   140    140
279    139    139
279    139    139
7730   140    140
278    139    139
12180  139    139
279   3660   3660
279    140    140
15443  139    139
278    139    139
18108 5527   5164
279    140    140
```

I want to convert this data by; 
Sum every 5 rows of each column (individually) and then divide by 10.

Desired output;

```
 X61253,X61613,X66198
 139.4,69.7,69.7
 1219,69.7,69.7
 2845.9,421.7,421.7
```

Used Excel Formula `=sum(1:5)/10`, =sum(6:10)/10, =sum(11:15)/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a need to promote `rowsum` (plafort's "df"):

```
rowsum(df, rep(seq_len(ceiling(nrow(df) / 5)), each = 5)[seq_len(nrow(df))]) / 10
#  X61253 X61613 X66198
#1  139.4   69.7   69.7
#2 1219.0   69.7   69.7
#3 2845.9  421.7  421.7
#4 1866.5  580.6  544.3
```

Comment: Like your one line solution inspired by Plafort's. 
further cleanness in data- Some of the column data is shorter than others, thats why where there is no data in those row,when I run this code in emply cells Err:511 showup. Is there any way we can get rid off that , also I am still getting Index columns along with my result? which I dont want. please help.

Comment: @Knight : Could you post sample data that reproduce the problem? I'm not sure I understand what's going on

Answer (score 3):

One solution:

```
library("plyr")
ss <- seq(0,nrow(x)-1)%/%5         ## grouping variable
dd <- ddply(x,.(ss),colSums)/10
```

By popular demand, with base R only:

```
dfs <- split(x,ss)  ## ss as constructed above
do.call(rbind,lapply(dfs,colSums))/10
```

Could also be done with `dplyr`, `data.table` ...

Comment: Ben, for some reason I can't install the plyr package on my RStudio- Is there any other simpler way ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution:

```
index <- seq(5,nrow(df), by=5)
splitup <- function(vec) {
  s <- split(vec,cumsum(tabulate(index+1, length(vec)))); 
  lapply(s, function(v) sum(v)/10)
}

sapply(df, splitup)
  X61253 X61613 X66198
0 139.4  69.7   69.7  
1 1219   69.7   69.7  
2 2845.9 421.7  421.7 
3 1866.5 580.6  544.3
```

Credit to @akrun for the idea a while back. One thing to note is that your example has 18 rows. With your data, do you need extra rows ignored?

## Alternate

Here's an alternate function that shows you what intervals have been used:

```
index <- seq(5,nrow(df), by=5)
splitup <- function(vec) {
  s <- split(vec, cut(seq_along(vec), c(-Inf, index, Inf))); 
  lapply(s, function(v) sum(v)/10)
}
sapply(df, splitup)
          X61253 X61613 X66198
(-Inf,5]  139.4  69.7   69.7  
(5,10]    1219   69.7   69.7  
(10,15]   2845.9 421.7  421.7 
(15, Inf] 1866.5 580.6  544.3
```

Credit to @Ananda Mahto for the alternate idea.

## Data

```
df <- read.table(text="X61253 X61613 X66198
279    140    140
279    139    139
278    139    139
279    140    140
279    139    139
278    139    139
3624   140    140
279    139    139
279    139    139
7730   140    140
278    139    139
12180  139    139
279   3660   3660
279    140    140
15443  139    139
278    139    139
18108 5527   5164
279    140    140", header=T)
```

Comment: Either of solution won't work @platfort 
Error in seq.default(5, nrow(df), by = 5) : 'to' must be of length 1

Comment: I just copied and pasted the data again and it worked still. Are you using the data in my answer to test first?

Comment: @Knight, if you don't have a variable `df` defined then `nrow(df)` will be `NULL` (since `df` is the name of a built-in R function)

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

```
a <- as.matrix(DF)
dim <- c(5, ceiling(nrow(a) / 5), ncol(a))
#pad with NA
a <- rbind(a, matrix(NA, ncol = ncol(a), nrow = 5 * dim[2] - nrow(a)))
#turn into 5*4*3 array
dim(a) <- dim

res <- colSums(a, na.rm = TRUE) / 10
colnames(res) <- names(DF)
res
#     X61253 X61613 X66198
#[1,]  139.4   69.7   69.7
#[2,] 1219.0   69.7   69.7
#[3,] 2845.9  421.7  421.7
#[4,] 1866.5  580.6  544.3
```